# Валидация типа в json golang

Tags: golang

Пишу http сервер, который принимает json. Есть структура:

```
type AuthModel struct {
    Username string
    Password string
}
```

Допустим пользователь отправляет такой json:

```
{
    "username": "user",
    "password": 1234
}
```

Задача его провалидировать и указать клиенту на его ошибки. После валидации я ожидаю получить: `Invalid password type. Allow: string` Или что-то подобное, неважно, главное чтобы было понятно в чём ошибка клиента.

Когда я пытаюсь распарсить этот json в структуру с помощью `json.Unmarshal` то сталкиваюсь с такой ошибкой: `json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field AuthModel.password of type string`. Не буду же я клиенту возвращать такой текст. Пытаться парсить его я думаю глупо (хотя если нет других способов...). Если я проигнорирую эту ошибку, то в структуре просто будет пустое поле `password` и не понятно проблема в том что оно было не того типа или просто не заполнено.

Как тут поступить? Есть готовые решения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type AuthModel struct {
    Username string
    Password string
}

var data = `
{
    "username": "user",
    "password": 1234
}
`

func main() {
    var c AuthModel
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &c)
    if err != nil {
        switch e := err.(type) {
        case *json.UnmarshalTypeError:
            log.Printf("UnmarshalTypeError: Value[%s] Type[%v]\n", e.Value, e.Type)
            retError := fmt.Errorf("Invalid json field[%s] type: got: %s, want: %v", e.Field, e.Value, e.Type)
            panic(retError)
        case *json.InvalidUnmarshalError:
            log.Printf("InvalidUnmarshalError: Type[%v]\n", e.Type)
        default:
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v", c)
}
```

```
2021/08/30 10:50:22 UnmarshalTypeError: Value[number] Type[string]
panic: Invalid json field[Password] type: got: number, want: string
```

лучше всего в таких ситуациях просто возвращать `http.StatusBadRequest`, для валидации данных попробуйте [go-playground/validator](http://github.com/go-playground/validator). validator позволяет валидировать входящие данные от пользователя, например, что пароль должен быть >10 символов

Answer (score -2):

Переменная Password в структуре у вас типа string, а вы отправляете json с переменной Password с типом int.

**1 Решение:**
Изменить структуру на:

```
type AuthModel struct {
    Username string
    Password int
}
```

**2 Решение:**
Изменить отправляемый json:

```
{
    "username": "user",
    "password": "1234" //поместили в кавычки, теперь это переменная типа string и соответствует тому, что у вас стоит в структуре
}
```

Comment: Вы вообще вопрос читали? Я специально туда `int` подставляю, потому что клиент может тоже самое делать. Задача объяснить клиенту что он не так делает

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Мой совет: прекрати учить языки, если ты не можешь проверить какие символы вводит клиент, то серьозно, лучше рисованием заняться

Comment: Ну раз умный такой напиши как проверить в go

Comment: Тут даже не в валидацит стоит проблема, в отправляемом json ставь везде string, далее на сервере конвертируй в int и ставь это всё в try/catch - выдаёт ошибку - отлично, чел помимо цифр написал так-же буквы. Далее всё в массив char делаешь и считаешь подходи ли пароль по твоим критериям. Это не фриланс и никто тебе не будет писать готовую обёртку

Comment: @antoshka иди отдохни) Отправляемый json не я формирую, его формирует клиент и важно объяснить ему что он делает неправильно. Где ты в golang видел `try` и `catch`? Куда ты лезешь если ты об этом языке ничего не знаешь? Я без тебя знаю как это делается в других языках. Я спрашиваю как это сделать в golang

Comment: Мне тебя очень жаль, если ты без try/catch не можешь проверить есть ли в строке символы